# How to add date/time exception to recurring Google calendar event

Tags: json, google-calendar-api

I have code that is creating Google calendar entries (recurring events) using the Google calendar API.  This is working fine. Now I am trying to add exceptions to certain instances.  I've got it working for deleted instances (by using the EXDATE parameter) but I'm having trouble changing the date/time of an instance.  I am following the instructions found here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents

After I create the basic recurring event, I retrieve a list of all instances. For testing, I am pulling out the entire section of json that applies to the instance I want to change, for example:

```
{
        "kind": "calendar#event",
        "etag": "\"3032281375946000\"",
        "id":   "_69j3ge9iccp68or1c8p3ac1nccpm8p356gpj8pb66koj2c32c5h0_20180130T203000Z",
        "status":   "confirmed",
        "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=XzY5ajNnZTlpY2NwNjhvcjFjOHAzYWMxbmNjcG04cDM1NmdwajhwYjY2a29qMmMzMmM1aDBfMjAxODAxMzBUMjAzMDAwWiBqbWNrYXk5MzUxQG0",
        "created":  "2018-01-16T20:08:56.000Z",
        "updated":  "2018-01-17T00:13:59.277Z",
        "summary":  "Recurring test with deletes and changes",
        "description":  "\n",
        "location": "SEattle",
        "creator":  {
            "email":    "jmckay9351@gmail.com",
            "displayName":  "Jeffrey McKay",
            "self": true
        },
        "organizer":    {
            "email":    "jmckay9351@gmail.com",
            "displayName":  "Jeffrey McKay",
            "self": true
        },
        "start":    {
            "dateTime": "2018-01-30T13:30:00-08:00"
        },
        "end":  {
            "dateTime": "2018-01-30T14:00:00-08:00"
        },
        "recurringEventId": "_69j3ge9iccp68or1c8p3ac1nccpm8p356gpj8pb66koj2c32c5h0",
        "originalStartTime":    {
            "dateTime": "2018-01-30T12:30:00-08:00"
        },
        "iCalUID":  "2f892c2dcab2507c3dde434ef5110bab",
        "sequence": 0,
        "reminders":    {
            "useDefault":   false,
            "overrides":    [{
                    "method":   "popup",
                    "minutes":  15
                }]
}
}
```

Then I do a http PUT of this data to this URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/jmckay9351@gmail.com/events/_69j3ge9iccp68or1c8p3ac1nccpm8p356gpj8pb66koj2c32c5h0_20180130T203000Z

What I get back is a http error 400, and the error message in the returned json is "Missing end time".  I get the same response regardless of how much or little data I feed into the PUT. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: For debugging purposes, can you first try it in the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#try-it) if what you're doing works?

Answer (score 0):

OK I've got this working now - I don't understand what was wrong with my libcurl PUT code, but I changed it to be a POST with a custom request of "PUT" and that seemed to get to data correctly uploaded.